# How to build a SE community around a specific topic?

Tags: discussion

I really appreciate the Q&A style of SE. I would like to move some science- and programming-related discussions that are currently taking place via other channels (mailing lists, private emails, facebook, etc.) to StackExchange. How should I start building the community?

- Which of SE websites is a good starting point for testing?
- Should I add some sample questions myself?
- How do I encourage more people to contribute?
- When should I start a new project in Area51?

All your suggestions are much welcome!

Comment: What kind of discussions are there? Do they belong in a current SE site? Which one? If not, what topic are they? Also, how much power do you have on the community? Will they listed to your suggestions?

Comment: There are some related projects in Area51 (such as neuroinformatics) and SE (computational science), but none of them is very popular in my field. I guess the problem is the critical mass necessary to encourage people to move to SE. The community is quite large, so my impact is rather small, but it would be nice to have a small sub-community around SE.

Comment: "science- and programming-related **discussions**" SE doesn't harbor discussion forums.

Comment: "Neuroinformatics" suggests [Cognitive Sciences](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/faq) might be a place to look, hard to say without knowing what in particular you're looking for though